# Trigger a button private sub when the user double click a document

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to trigger the button that will handle the extraction of the selected document once the user double click the document listed in the form like the screen shot below

[image: ScreenShot]

So I went in the properties and configured:

```
Private Sub ParamName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
call Forms!FormName.Extract_Click
End Sub
```

With no success , I also tried :

```
Private Sub ParamName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
     Forms!FormName.Extract_Click
    End Sub
```

Inside the form , the sub is declared as below :

```
   Private Sub Extract_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
     //.... //do work 
end sub
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is this a sheet and a form, or just a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't, and even if you could (or in contexts where you can), you shouldn't.

Longer answer: don't implement any logic directly in event handlers. *Invoke* the logic from the handlers:

```
Private Sub SomeControl_SomeEvent()
    DoTheThing
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub DoTheThing()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

That `Public` member can live in a standard module, and thus can be invoked by anything anywhere - from a button on some form, or from another button on another form, or whatever you need to invoke it from.

But don't invoke event handler procedures yourself. Event handlers *handle events*, they're invoked by the VBA runtime: leave it that way and live prosper.

Comment: Excellent , I have declared a function called Public Function ExtractFile() then I could invoke it from anywhere using Call Forms("MyFormName").ExtractFile

Comment: A `Function` normally returns a value, and explicit `Call` syntax has been obsolete for the better part of the past 25 years, but yeah that's the idea.

Comment: Do you suggest I use a `procedure` instead of the `Function` and I remove the `Call` syntax? P.S : I'm a beginner and I would like to know expert feedback

Comment: Thank you a lot , one last question , your add-in looks pretty impressive , does it have the feature of high-lighting variable and object in the vba IDE  like any other IDE? (which does not exist so far )

Comment: That's planned. Expect code-block folding, in-editor inspection results (similar to Roslyn/R#), and an actually useful intellisense too!

Comment: Will definitely give it a try !  Thanks a lot !